# SVN Tortoise folders' icon

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, directory

This is a folder I use with SVN Tortoise:

[image]

How do I add these icons to the folders?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you were using TortoiseSVN before, you should already have basic knowledge on what such kind of icon means.  Can you be clear on your meaning of "add icons to folders" ?

Answer (score 0):

those icons should be automatically be there once you do svn checkout if not try svn update using tortoise svn. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The icons where provide (for example) by [TortoiseSVN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zO5zx.png).
You have to install TortoiseSVN, did you do?

If you still have TortoiseSVN installed please check Settings. It should look like this:

[image]